# Getting border to wrap around entirety of element

Tags: html, css

I am creating a link that looks like a button. One thing I am running into is if I have more than one word for the anchor the link/button text is going to the next line. It is fine if the anchor text goes to the next line, but the border then does not wrap around the entire thing. It looks as if the border breaks (not sure of the correct terminology).

See the image below for a reference: (Sorry image upload keeps failing)

Does anyone know how I can

```css
.container {
  width: 40%;
  background: gray;
 } 
.mainLinkWrapC {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.mainLink {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  color: #b82222;
  border: 2px solid #b82222;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mainLinkWrapC">
    <a href="#" class="mainLink">Hard Guarding Solutions</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set `display: block` to your `.mainLink`

```css
.container {
  width: 40%;
  background: gray;
 } 
.mainLinkWrapC {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.mainLink {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  color: #b82222;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #b82222;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mainLinkWrapC">
    <a href="#" class="mainLink">Hard Guarding Solutions</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Paul You're welcome. Glad to help. Can you mark it as answered?

Comment: The only thing about this is that now the buttons are very wide. Where as before they just wrapped the link. Any idea?

Comment: You should adjust the `padding` value accordingly to your need or simply remove it as to wrap the link neatly.

Comment: @Paul Did you accomplish your wanted? or do you need to me to adjust the code?